# 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position: truncated /uXXXX escape

Tags: python

I know that the way to do this is either add an r at the front or change the \ to a \ or /. But none of that seems to be working. (I'm running on ubuntu)

````
print(homedir)


import socket
hostname = socket.gethostname()
print(hostname)


with open(f"{homedir}/.config/blender/2.81/scripts/addons/Renderpresets/presets/presets.txt") as presetsfile:
    presetsdata = presetsfile.read()

with open(f"{homedir}/.config/blender/2.81/scripts/addons/Renderpresets/presets/uirow.txt") as uirowfile:
    uirowdata = uirowfile.read()

with open(f"{homedir}/.config/blender/2.81/scripts/addons/Renderpresets/presets/register.txt") as registerfile:
    registerdata = registerfile.read()

with open(f"{homedir}/.config/blender/2.81/scripts/addons/Renderpresets/presets/unregister.txt") as unregisterfile:
    unregisterdata = unregisterfile.read()

with open(f"{homedir}/.config/blender/2.81/scripts/addons/Renderpresets/presets/namemain.txt") as namemainfile:
    namemaindata = namemainfile.read()```
````

Comment: where do you get the error, what is the value of `homedir`  consider using `pathlib`

Comment: dont worry it was an issue with another file

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a general python problem, unrelated to blender.